# Is it possible to pass values from two instances of the same Scala class

Tags: scala, class, oop, instance-variables

Say I have this situation

```
 class Pipe {
    var vel = 3.4
    var V = 300
    var a = 10.2
    var in = ???
    var TotV = V+in
    var out = TotV*a/vel

    }

 val pipe1 = new Pipe
 val pipe2 = new Pipe
```

The in variable is were my problem is, what i'd like to do is get the out variable from pipe1 and feed that in as the in variable for pipe 2 effectively to join the two pipes but I cant figure out if this is even possible in the same class. So I can do it manually but need to know if its possible to do in the class.

```
 pipe2.in = pipe1.out
```

my attempted fix was to add an ID field then try and use that to reference an instance with a higher id field but that doesnt seem doable. ie

```
class Pipe(id:Int) {
    var vel = 3.4
    var V = 300
    var a = 10.2
    var in = Pipe(id+1).out //this is the sticking point, I want to reference instances of this class and use their out value as in value for instances with a lower ID
    var TotV = V+in
    var out = TotV*a/vel

    }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where is `RR` coming from?

Comment: my mistake , meant pipe

Comment: Where is `pipe` coming from? is it a method? and what is `id`? It might help if you describe what exactly you're trying to model with this class.

Comment: what is `Pipe(id+1)` supposed to do? create a new instance of `Pipe`? (wrong syntax for that)... obtain a reference to an existing instance? (you would need some sort of store)... how do 2 instances of `Pipe` generally differ? please post more complete code (why do you even need more instances?)

Comment: Since `in` is a `var` (suspicious) why not add a setter for it? `def attach(p:Pipe) = in = p.out`

Comment: This looks like it could be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: jwvh , you're right its an XY problem but only added my attempt because its bad form to not even try and solve your own problem before posting here or so i'v read.And Alvaro, Pipe(id+1) is the general idea of what i'm trying to achieve. There isnt any more code, I just want to get the out value from an instance with a higher id and use that as in the in value for an instance with a lower id. I dno if that explains it well enough

Comment: @Delta1x, I don't think you understand what an XY problem is (follow the link I previously posted). It has nothing to do with solving "your own problem before posting here." It's all about trying to solve X so that you can then solve Y, but it turns out X is a bad way to solve Y. If this really is an XY problem then you should ask for help with Y and not X.

Comment: @Delta1x, the thing that jwvh says is that you should stop and go one level up in abstraction and describe your **_high-level_** problem that you are trying to solve with this whole `Pipe` class. Then somebody can suggest a better solution to the high-level problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining a companion object for the class and passing in the upstream pipe as an optional parameter to the factory method, then extracting its in value and passing it to the class constructor, as follows:

```
object Pipe {
  def apply(upstreamPipe: Option[Pipe]): Pipe = {
    val inValue = upstreamPipe match {
      case Some(pipe) => pipe.out
      case None => 0 // or whatever your default value is
    new Pipe(inValue)
}
```

You would then call

```
val pipe1 = Pipe(None)
val pipe2 = Pipe(Some(pipe1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is not clear now. Under certain assumptions what you describe looks like what is now called ["FRP" aka "Functional Reactive Programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming). If you want to do it in a serious way, you probably should take a look at some mature library such as [RxScala](http://reactivex.io/rxscala/) or [Monix](https://monix.io/) that handle many important in the real world details such as error handling or scheduling/threading and many others.

For a simple task you might roll out a simple custom implementation like this:

```
trait Observable {
  def subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber): RxConnection
}

trait RxConnection {
  def disconnect(): Unit
}

trait Subscriber {
  def onChanged(): Unit
}

trait RxOut[T] extends Observable {
  def currentValue: Option[T]
}

class MulticastObservable extends Observable with Subscriber {
  private val subscribers: mutable.Set[Subscriber] = mutable.HashSet()

  override def onChanged(): Unit = subscribers.foreach(s => s.onChanged())

  override def subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber): RxConnection = {
    subscribers.add(subscriber)
    new RxConnection {
      override def disconnect(): Unit = subscribers.remove(subscriber)
    }
  }
}


abstract class BaseRxOut[T](private var _lastValue: Option[T]) extends RxOut[T] {
  private val multicast = new MulticastObservable()

  protected def lastValue: Option[T] = _lastValue

  protected def lastValue_=(value: Option[T]): Unit = {
    _lastValue = value
    multicast.onChanged()
  }

  override def currentValue: Option[T] = lastValue

  override def subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber): RxConnection = multicast.subscribe(subscriber)
}

class RxValue[T](initValue: T) extends BaseRxOut[T](Some(initValue)) {
  def value: T = this.lastValue.get

  def value_=(value: T): Unit = {
    this.lastValue = Some(value)
  }
}

trait InputConnector[T] {
  def connectInput(input: RxOut[T]): RxConnection
}

class InputConnectorImpl[T] extends BaseRxOut[T](None) with InputConnector[T] {
  val inputHolder = new RxValue[Option[(RxOut[T], RxConnection)]](None)

  private def updateValue(): Unit = {
    lastValue = for {inputWithDisconnect <- inputHolder.value
                     value <- inputWithDisconnect._1.currentValue}
      yield value
  }

  override def connectInput(input: RxOut[T]): RxConnection = {
    val current = inputHolder.value
    if (current.exists(iwd => iwd._1 == input))
      current.get._2
    else {
      current.foreach(iwd => iwd._2.disconnect())
      inputHolder.value = Some(input, input.subscribe(() => this.updateValue()))
      updateValue()
      new RxConnection {
        override def disconnect(): Unit = {
          if (inputHolder.value.exists(iwd => iwd._1 == input)) {
            inputHolder.value.foreach(iwd => iwd._2.disconnect())
            inputHolder.value = None
            updateValue()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

abstract class BaseRxCalculation[Out] extends BaseRxOut[Out](None) {

  protected def registerConnectors(connectors: InputConnectorImpl[_]*): Unit = {
    connectors.foreach(c => c.subscribe(() => this.recalculate()))
  }

  private def recalculate(): Unit = {
    var newValue = calculateOutput()
    if (newValue != lastValue) {
      lastValue = newValue
    }
  }

  protected def calculateOutput(): Option[Out]
}

case class RxCalculation1[In1, Out](func: Function1[In1, Out]) extends BaseRxCalculation[Out] {
  private val conn1Impl = new InputConnectorImpl[In1]

  def conn1: InputConnector[In1] = conn1Impl // show to the outer world only InputConnector

  registerConnectors(conn1Impl)

  override protected def calculateOutput(): Option[Out] = {
    for {v1 <- conn1Impl.currentValue}
      yield func(v1)
  }
}

case class RxCalculation2[In1, In2, Out](func: Function2[In1, In2, Out]) extends BaseRxCalculation[Out] {
  private val conn1Impl = new InputConnectorImpl[In1]

  def conn1: InputConnector[In1] = conn1Impl // show to the outer world only InputConnector

  private val conn2Impl = new InputConnectorImpl[In2]

  def conn2: InputConnector[In2] = conn2Impl // show to the outer world only InputConnector

  registerConnectors(conn1Impl, conn2Impl)

  override protected def calculateOutput(): Option[Out] = {
    for {v1 <- conn1Impl.currentValue
         v2 <- conn2Impl.currentValue}
      yield func(v1, v2)
  }
}

// add more RxCalculationN if needed
```

And you can use it like this:

```
def test(): Unit = {

  val pipe2 = new RxCalculation1((in: Double) => {
    println(s"in = $in")
    val vel = 3.4
    val V = 300
    val a = 10.2
    val TotV = V + in
    TotV * a / vel
  })

  val in1 = new RxValue(2.0)
  println(pipe2.currentValue)
  val conn1 = pipe2.conn1.connectInput(in1)
  println(pipe2.currentValue)
  in1.value = 3.0
  println(pipe2.currentValue)
  conn1.disconnect()
  println(pipe2.currentValue)
}
```

which prints

> None
>   
>  in = 2.0
>   
>  Some(905.9999999999999)
>   
>  in = 3.0
>   
>  Some(909.0)
>   
>  None

Here your "pipe" is `RxCalculation1` (or other `RxCalculationN`) which wraps a function and you can "connect" and "disconnect" other "pipes" or just "values" to various inputs and start a chain of updates.